# Update table on matching text type of data

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have following table

[alt text http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/930/town.png](http://img683.imageshack.us/img683/930/town.png)

I want to update its TownId from following table on matching TownId.

[alt text http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/6453/townid.png](http://img269.imageshack.us/img269/6453/townid.png)

The desired result of Table 1 is

[alt text http://img132.imageshack.us/img132/8184/townidupdaed.png](http://img132.imageshack.us/img132/8184/townidupdaed.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE  t1 
SET t1.townid=t2.townid
FROM table1 t1 
JOIN table2 t2 ON t1.town=t2.town
```

Comment: Just keep in mind that if two rows exist with the same exact town name, the results will be unpredictable as to which ID you will get.

Comment: Tom that is certainly true. Hopefully the database design precluded that though. If it didn't, then the poster may need to fix the design first.

Comment: Thank, DB design is ok so no problem.